# Parsing json including null result NameError with Python 2.7

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I want to pick out "b"tag from this json data.
But it results NameError.
Please tell how to improve this code.

```
json_data = {"one": null,
         "two": {"a": "1", "b": null},
         "three": "3"
         }

if __name__=="__main__":
    new_data = json.decode(json_data)
    json = json.loads(new_data)
    print json["two"]["b"]
```

Comment: Please post the exception with your question, including the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here is you are trying to decode an object, not a string containing JSON. This means that Python is parsing your data as a `dict` literal, which results in it trying to find a value for `null` which, naturally, doesn't exist in Python. Instead, you want to make a string:

```
json_data = '''{"one": null,
         "two": {"a": "1", "b": null},
         "three": "3"
         }'''
```

Here we use triple quotes (`'''`) to define a multi-line string.

This should work as expected. I presume you are simply giving an example, it is worth noting, however, that this is rather pointless in this context, and you would be better off just defining the Python data structure directly, and not using JSON at all.

Comment: I try print json_data["two"]["b"], but it results TypeError:string indices must be inegers,not str

Comment: You still need to do `json.loads()` - if you don't want to take that extra step, just define it as a `dict` and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because you're trying to pass a Python dictionary to a non-existent `json.decode()` function. The following addresses these issues by manually turning `json_data` into a string and passing that directly to `json.loads()` which will turn the `null`s encountered into `None`s.

```
import json

json_data = '''{"one": null,
                "two": {"a": "1", "b": null},
                "three": "3"
               }'''

if __name__=="__main__":
    json = json.loads(json_data)
    print json["two"]["b"]
```

Output:

```
None
```